# Why would French fit science, and English fit literature?

Tags: chomsky

I happened upon [this on r/asklinguistics](https://redd.it/9dks66) that, being 9 months old, has time-barred comments. I've a shade rectified some mistakes and rewritten it.

> Noam Chomsky, in some interview, said that scholars in the 19th or even 18th century decided that French would be the language of science and English the language of literature.

1. Where did Chomsky contend this?
2. Why did these scholars reckon that French befits science, rather than English?
3. And why English for literature, and not e.g.German or Italian?

Comment: I don't knw the Chomsky reference, but there's a chapter on this idea in Trudgill and Bauer, _Language Myths_ (I can't find my copy right now). Typically it was French natural philosophers (scientists) who argued that French was especially logical, and Italian poets who argued that Italian was especially poetical etc.

Comment: No Chomsky reference either but your question triggered a very dim recollection of someone's famous quotation listing several languages, along the lines of "..I would use lang1 for this, lang2 for that.." and so on. Unfortunately, i can't recall it properly and will have to try to google it up.

Comment: Got it, completely irrelevant to the question. It was [Lomonosov's quote](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2492939?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) with a reference to Charles V who *allegedly* also coined a similar phrase (some believe this to be a myth, though).

Comment: [Related](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/cultural-bias-in-early-modern-western-linguistics/31552#31552): 18th century attitudes, focusing on French perspectives from the _Académie française_.